# Fringe contrast in Michelson-Morley Interferometer

Tags: optics, interference

The sodium D-lines are a pair of narrow, closely spaced, approximately equal intensity spectral lines with a mean wavelength of approximately 589 nm, with wavelength difference 0.60 nm. A Michelson interferometer is set up to study the D-lines from a sodium lamp. High contrast fringes are seen for zero pathlength difference between the two arms of the interferometer. The fringes disappear when the pathlength difference is increased to 0.29 mm.

**Question**: If the spectral lines have approximately Gaussian shapes, with a width of 50 pm (taken between the points of the line shape where the intensity falls to e −1/2 of the peak intensity), what is the maximum fringe contrast (visibility) seen for a pathlength difference of around 4 mm?

What is the "line shape" and what is it plotted as a function of? Considering that the width of the peaks in the line shape is given in units pm, I suppose it must be some sort of length. However, I am not sure what length, because the one on the screen is not general enough (it depends on the distance etc.).

Fringe visibility: 
$$ 
v = \frac{I_{\max}-I_{\min}}{I_{\max}+I_{\min}} 
$$

Comment: Can you sketch and describe your experimental setup, so I can answer more fully? See [my answer here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/357785/26076) for discussion of coherence on visibility: from the formulas there, the $1/e$ coherence length for a 50pm wide source is about 1.5mm, therefore the visibility of fringes when this source acts on a path difference of 4mm is of the order of $\exp(-(4/1.5)^2)\approx 0.001$. Only visible in high SNR conditions.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance I am afraid it will be hard to supply more information about the set-up, other than that it is a Michelson-Morley interferometer. This is a theoretical question I have been given, not an actual experiment I have performed.